# PHP: Show yes/no confirmation dialog

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

My PHP page has a link to delete one MySQL table datum. I want it to be in such a way that when I click the 'delete' link a confirmation box should appear and it should ask  "are you sure, you want to delete?", with two buttons: 'yes' and 'no'. When I click yes, I want to delete the MySQL table's data and when I click no, nothing should happen.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: You should always use a form/post button to confirm something like this. Never rely on Javascript. Read [this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx) to understand why!

Answer (score 59):

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">My Link</a>
```

Comment: the most simple and effective way to do this, work like charm !, thanks.

Comment: Was working on Yii-framework, and somehow seeing this put htis way made me realize it on yii too, `'options'=>array('onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?");')`

Answer (score 19):

```
<input name="_delete_" type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use JavaScript to prompt you:

Found this here - [Example](http://www.psacake.com/web/iw.asp)

```
<script>
function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
   document.location = delUrl;
  }
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:confirmDelete('delete.page?id=1')">Delete</a>
```

Another way

```
<a href="delete.page?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
```

**Warning**: This JavaScript will not stop the records from being deleted if they just navigate to the final url - delete.page?id=1 in their browser

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is create a delete page that shows a confirmation form if the request method is "GET" and deletes the data if the method was "POST" and the user chose the "Yes" option.

Then, in the page with the delete link, I add an onclick function (or just use the [jQuery confirm plugin](http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin)) that uses AJAX to post to the link, bypassing the confirmation page.

Here's the idea in pseudo code:

delete.php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['confirm'] == 'Yes') {
        delete_record($_REQUEST['id']); // From GET or POST variables
    }
    redirect($_POST['referer']);
}
?>

<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    Are you sure?
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="No">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">
</form>
```

Page with delete link:

```
<script>
    function confirmDelete(link) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            doAjax(link.href, "POST"); // doAjax needs to send the "confirm" field
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href="delete.php?id=1234" onclick="return confirmDelete(this);">Delete record</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are You Confirm Deletion');" href="delete_customer.php?a=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text" style="color: white; width:86px; height:37px;" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span><span><strong></a></strong></span>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the attribute onClick for both i.e. 'ok' & 'cancel' condition like ternary operator

**Scenario:**
Here is the scenario that I wants to show confirm box which will ask for 'ok' or 'cancel' while performing a delete action. In that I want if user click on 'ok' then the form action will redirect to page location and on cancel page will not respond.

Adding further explanation i'm having one button with type="submit" which is originally use default form action of form tag. and I want above scenario on delete button with same input type.

**So below code is working properly for me**

```
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete ?')?this.form.action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>':false;"
```

**Full code**

```
<input type="submit" name="action" id="Delete" value="Delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete ?')?this.form.action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>':false;">
```

And by the way I'm implementing this code as inline in html element using PHP. so that's why I used 'echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']'.

I hope it will work for you also.
Thank You

Comment: Please add some furthe explanation. Why do you need to modify the form action? Why not set the form action intially?

Comment: Actually a form action added initially in form tag which is used by "Add detail" button with input type="submit". and I want above scenario on delete button with same input type so thats why i passed different form action in it.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP way of doing this would be using a dialog system inside php.for example GTKDialogs:
http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/articles/setup-a-dialog-box---Part-2---simple-yes-no-dialog.php
The javacript way is probably a bit easier, but remember when javascript is turned off, this does not work (except if you check javascript to be enabled and then add this!?)
This could be with a onclick handler like  tsvanharen posted, or with a simple text dialog inside the page instead of a nagging popup.

```
<a onClick="$('deletefromtable').show();"></a>
<div id="deletefromtable" style="display:none;">
 Do you really want to do this?<br/>
 <a href="deleteit.php">Yes</a>|<a onClick="$('deletefromtable').hide();">No</a>
</div>
```

I use prototype (hence the $() tag and the show()/hide()) for it. but you can easily change it to work without prototype:

```
<a onClick='document.getElementById("deletefromtable").style.display = "block";' href="#">click here to delete</a>
<div id="deletefromtable" style="display:none;">
 Do you really want to do this?<br/>
 <a href="deleteit.php">Yes</a>|<a onClick='document.getElementById("deletefromtable").style.display = "none";' href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

Again, this does not work without javascript, but almost no options do.

Comment: Even if phpgtk was installed on the server (which is nonsense, as it requires a graphical interface, that is never installed on web servers running Linux), it would open that dialog box on the server, and not inside the browser nor on the user's machine : you cannot, from the server, open a GTK window on the client

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting something, you should always use POST and not GET, so using confirm() is a bad idea.  What I do in your situation is use a modal popup like [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) and display a form with yes/no buttons inside the popup.

Comment: how does `confirm()` prevent you from using POST?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found is here.

**HTML CODE**

```
<a href="delete.cfm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Delete</a>
```

**ADD THIS TO HEAD SECTION**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

You should add Jquery and Bootstrap for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"/>`
you can perform this action on Button too!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to do it and figured it out like this using forms and the formaction attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="del_something" formaction="<addresstothispage>" value="delete" />
<?php if(isset($_POST['del_something'])) print '<div>Are you sure? <input type="submit" name="del_confirm" value="yes!" formaction="action.php" />
<input type="submit" name="del_no" value="no!" formaction="<addresstothispage>" />';?>
```

action.php would check for isset($_POST['del_confirm']) and call the corresponding php script (for database actions or whatever). Voilà, no javascript needed. Using the formaction attribute, the delete button can be part of any form and still call a different form action (such as refer back to the same page, but with the button set).

If the button was pressed, the confirm buttons will show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>
    <a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');" href="'.base_url('category/delete_category/'.$row->category_id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete Coupon</a>
</td>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Please share more details. Why does your code contain inline PHP without any PHP tags?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272899/confirmation-prompt-before-php-execution) question:

```
function confirmation($link_delete,$link_keep,$message) ///confirm box pop up
    {
        echo "<script>javascript:
        var ask = confirm('".$message."');
        if(ask==true)
        {
            window.location ='".$link_delete."' 
        }
        else
        {
            window.location ='".$link_keep."'    
        }
        </script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In php section:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["delete_plan"])){
    //deleting
    }
}
```

in html:

```
<form id="form_delete" style="display:none;" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    Are you sure?
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="delete_plan" value="Yes"/>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="No" onClick="$('form#form_delete').hide();$('input#delete_confirm').show();"/>
</form>
<input id="delete_confirm"  type="button" class="button" value="Delete" onClick="$('form#form_delete').show(); $(this).hide();"/>
```

Form is hidden at 1st. On "Delete" button click form is displayed, Delete button hides. "No" button in the form reverts it back. "Yes" proceeds to delete, then page reloads and initial view returns, i.e. form is hidden, "Delete" button is not.

If your are dealing with many rows of data, you need to add a row id to form_delete and delete_confirm.

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="return confirm('Log Out?')? window.open('?user=logout','_self'): void(0);"
```

Did this script and afterwards i tought i go check the internet too.

Yes this is an old threat but as there seems not to be any similar version i thought i'd contribute.

Easiest & simplest way works on all browsers with/in any element or field.

You can change `window.open` to any other command to run when confirmation is `TRUE`, same with `void(0)` if conformation is `NULL` or canceled.

Comment: Please share more detais. Why do you ask for the user to log out if any database row should be deleted?