# PHP : Return a bool from Javascript confirm method

Tags: javascript, php, boolean, confirm

I want to ask the user if he wants to delete a line from the database, so I proceed like this :

```
<script>
function show_confirm() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

on the PHP page i call it like this :

```
print "<a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='return show_confirm();'> Google </a>";
$userAnswer = ???;
```

How do I know if the user pressed OK or CANCEL?  (so that i can do different treatement).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Do it another way, such as AJAX or a confirm page.

Comment: Confirm function do it all what u mentioned here....  if click on ok theen actio get performed Or processed other wise it remain on same page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238347/php-show-yes-no-confirmation-dialog

Comment: Use this `var x = confirm('Press a button');`. If the user clicks ok `x` will be `true` if the user clicks cancel the value of `x` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

User confirm on client side, and you want to do something on the server side.
As the comments says, use AJAX (I would suggest you to use a JS framework like jquery).

[AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp)

```
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
    // OK
} else {
    // CANCEL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is done before the page is shown, hence it is a pre-processor. It cannot respond to items when the page is show - that is the role of Javascript.

The best of doing this is to define a div (id answer for example), have your javascript pass something to a php page and put the answer in the div. Something like:

```
function show_confirm() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
       x = 1;
    } else {
       x = 0; }
    $("#answer").load("yourphpprocesspage.php?answer=" + x);

}
```

Simply then write something in PHP for the process page like:

```
<?php
  if ($_GET['answer'] == 1)
     {$text = "You pressed confirm";}
  else
     {$text = "Your pressed cancel"; }
?>
```

Then in the body of your processing page add after the

```
<?php echo $text; ?>
```

Comment: what is the use of checking the condition ==TRUE.?? if confirm is OK the result will be TRUE and and if() will work automatically

Comment: as he was a newbie I thought I would make it very clear

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quite simple and can be seen here [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P643L/1/)

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me">
```

The javascript part is:

```
 $("input").on("click", function() {
 var output = 1;
 if(confirm("You really??"))
   {
     output=0;
    }

  alert(output);
 });
```

The output is **0** when the user clicks **OK** and it is **1** when he clicks **Cancel**

> This is the AJAX POST Request about which you can read here:

```
$.POST("yourphpfile.php", data, fucntion(response) {
 if(!response) {
    alert("Server not responding");
 }
 else {
    //Do what ever you want.!!
 }
});
```

Also read this [AJAX REQUEST POST Type](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: In my question, I said that I wanted to get the TRUE or FALSE (0 or 1) in the PHP code, not in the javascript.. but thanks anyway..

Comment: Did you get it fixed or need help on your comment above..??

Comment: No, i'm trying to solve it with GET or POST method..

Comment: Do you want me to write a AJAX GET or POST for you.??

Comment: That would be really nice !
because i just started on PHP.. and, you know.. i'm still learning :) thanks in advance