# PHP form submission alert not working (no ajax)

Tags: javascript, php

This is my first question on StackOverflow - thanks in advance for your help!

I have an html form that emails me upon submission. The form submits successfully but I want it to display a submission confirmation message via pop up alert box before reloading the page. Any help is appreciated - though, I'll say now that I don't intend to use AJAX since I am not at all familiar yet. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="php/contactForm.php">
    <p class="formBox" id="nameBox">Name:</br><input type="text" id="contactName" name="contactName"></p>
    <p class="formBox" id="emailBox">Email:</br><input type="email" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail"></p>
    <p>Message:</br><textarea id="contactMessage" name="contactMessage"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

PHP in "contactForm.php":

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['contactName'];
$email = $_POST['contactEmail'];
$message = $_POST['contactMessage'];

$body = $name . "\n" . $email . "\n\n" . wordwrap($message);

$alert = "<script>alert('Thank you for reaching out! Someone will be in touch soon.')</script>";
echo $alert;

mail('email@notmyactualemail.com', 'New Message from Website Contact Form!', $body);
header("Location: ../connect.html");

?>
```

p.s. If it helps to know, I am hosting on GoDaddy.

Comment: If you want to do it without ajax, you can redirect the user to a custom confirmation page after sending the mail in your php. Other methods that I know will require ajax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Show yes/no confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238347/php-show-yes-no-confirmation-dialog)

Comment: Once you get more comfortable with PHP and JS, I would advise you to replace all the alerts with modals and flash messages. Alerts are intrusive and can be blocked by browsers, so you shouldn't rely on them as UI elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX works to run code without having to refresh your page. The PHP code you have now will run after the page reloads. Therefore, there is no way without AJAX to send a genuine confirmation message before the page reloads.

You can, however, use the javascript `onsubmit` property to make a confirmation alert once the form is submitted, but that will not guarantee that the form was indeed submitted without error. Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(){
  window.alert("This is the confirmation message!\n\nThank you for submitting");
}
```

```html
<form action="www.example.com" id="myForm" method="POST">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Fantastic - this is exactly the solution I was looking for. It may not be the ideal but it's fast and easy while I work on learning ajax. Thanks so much!